# Bluetooth not working on HP 15-BS1XX, how can I check which driver I need?

Tags: bluetooth, hp

I am using HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx. My Bluetooth is not working. How can I check whether the right Bluetooth driver is installed, and if necessary how can I install it?

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'; rfkill list`

Answer (score 1):

The `lshw` tool is among the best tools to check the hardware that can be seen under Linux on a specific system. It's highly recommended to use it with high privileges.

I'd suggest you to start with `sudo lshw -businfo` to get a first taste.
Then you can dive deeper with just `sudo lshw` (be warned: the output can be quite long to be read).

Then you can use a number of other tools like `lsusb` for USB related hardware, `lspci` for information about PCI-attached hardware and `lsscsi` for storage devices using the SCSI layer (almost all of them do). Man pages are available to tune the amount of details you want to get.

If you can dual-boot with another OS that can successfully use that hardware, please go on and take note about that hardware by inspecting the hardware details with that OS.

In any case, if your device isn't listed at all, that is likely meaning that it isn't supported by Linux or, at least, by the Ubuntu kernel you are using. Maybe an upgrade can help.